# Multilingual web application change div text?

Tags: asp.net, localization, multilingual

I am working with asp.net web application multilingual site.

I am using following link :

http://techaxe.com/2010/09/04/creating-multilingual-website-using-asp-net/

Here we have file in my App_LocalResource folder for change text content. It's work good with label control.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:AboutText%>"></asp:Label>
```

Here I want to change my div content as per selected language.

```
<div class="registration_content" runat="server">
                    <%$Resources:AboutText%> </div>
```

Please suggest me how I can change div content as per local resource variable.

Thanks for any suggestion..

Comment: There is a quite recent "tutorial" [here](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/) explaining step by step on how to deal with localization in asp.net MVC. This [blog post](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) seems also to provide useful information for you.

Comment: Are you sure you're working with ASP.NET MVC? If yes, please read this other [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875368/best-practice-for-asp-net-mvc-resource-files).

Comment: Hummm I am not using ASP.NET MVC I have simple web application.
Have seen following URL 
http://techaxe.com/2010/09/04/creating-multilingual-website-using-asp-net/

Comment: OK, now makes more sense... I'll edit the post to remove the `ASP.Net MVC` tag so the people is not confused (as I was).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `asp:Literal` tag:

```
<div class="registration_content" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:AboutText%>" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Very thanks for your support..
Here I need to change master page value as well using local resource file help me if you have any idea...
again thanks to you...