# Where do I put my local resources in MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, asp.net-mvc-4, embedded-resource

I am currently working on an mvc4 application. It needs to be multi lingual so therefore each of my views requires a resource file associated to it.

In the web forms world, I would be creating App_LocalResouces and have the resource files within this for my pages/user controls.

Being new to MVC I am not sure how this works - is it similar. For example for my razor views, where the resource file for the particular view reside. Same with my models and controllers, where does the resource file for such reside?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it done a lot of ways.  It's really based on preference.  My preference is to create a Resource folder and store the translated strings in one file with the name of the culture.  I then set the language in the web.config file and leave it up to the page to pull the correct strings.

Comment: Thanks for this information, could you outline what other ways you have seen it done also. Thanks

Comment: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx explains a great way.

Comment: You might take a glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875368/best-practice-for-asp-net-mvc-resource-files as well.