# mvc : I want to load my error message from resource file but i get attribute const error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resx

I want to create a multilingual `mvc` web site so I have been loading all my messages and labels from resource file and in  my validation i want show my message from the resource file but i am getting the following error.

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx).

That is, when applying an attribute to something, the arguments must be constant values such as const primitives (string, int, float, bool, double etc), enums, or type.

For example:

##Legal

```
[Required("This field is required.")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

##Error

```
[Required(SomeObject.ErrorMessageStringProperty)]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

If the string isn't a [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx), you cannot compile.

#Hint

[ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) classes have already addressed this issue. Instead of providing an `ErrorMessage` argument, you can provide an `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName`. These const values are then used to look up the appropriate error message for the culture.

e.g.

##Legal

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName="RequiredError")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

##Further reading

[How to localize ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192465/how-to-localize-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Multiple languages in an ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034/multiple-languages-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[DisplayName attribute from Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources)

[Best practice for ASP.NET MVC resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875368/best-practice-for-asp-net-mvc-resource-files)

##ASP.NET 5/Core

For devs coming across this post in the future and are seeking the .NET 5 reference... the following documentation cleared everything up for me.

[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: but my resource file created a static string eg     public static string ClaimamountlessthanBalanceamount {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("ClaimamountlessthanBalanceamount", resourceCulture);
            }
        }

Comment: That's a static property, not a const. Property values are not a legal argument in an attribute.

Comment: what's the best way to do it

Comment: I've added a section to hint you in the right direction. Use that information and the further reading for ideas.