# Access image file sitting within VS Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method code:

```
private Image GetMapIcon()
{
  //TODO Fix path
  return Image.FromFile("D:\\Work\\FindandCompare\\Main\\NHSChoices.FindAndCompare.Web\\Content\\img\\mapIcon.png");
}
```

As you can see the path will only work on my machine. I tried all sorts to get it to work without being so specific, but I couldn't! For example:

```
private Image GetMapIcon()
{
  //TODO Fix path
  return Image.FromFile(Url.Content("~/Content/img/mapIcon.png"));
}
```

The method is sitting within an MVC Controller.

I do not want to add a whole new Class Library project to the VS Solution to hold a resource. Is there an easier way that will work once this is deployed to the server?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875368/best-practice-for-asp-net-mvc-resource-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Server.MapPath`:

```
private Image GetMapIcon()
{
  return Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/mapIcon.png")
}
```

To include the image in the publish simply highlight the image in the solution explorer then change the 'Build action' to 'Content'.

Comment: Thanks, I had to pass that to `Image.FromFile()` and it now seems to work.